# HTML5 canvas paint zoom performance

Tags: javascript, html, performance, canvas

I have interesting question. I make paint with zoom function i painting on original canvas size: `500px x 500px` and i have 3 zoom levels 1x - it's original size, 2x - two times bigger and 3x.. I know few methods zooming

first is: recording all drawing coordinates and then zooming just redrawing multiplying recording points from select scale 1x 2x or 3x.

second is: have two layers original and max scale in this example 3x will be `1500px x 1500px` (because original is `500px x 500px`) ant painting in both layers but in second layer 3x bigger then we zooming just copy from max scale and paste into first layer and scaling it.

Question is what is better method for performance then i painting a lot of time about 30-60 minutes

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale ?

Comment: Use the first method.

Comment: Thanks @markE can you tell more about this methods why use first not second, why first method better and etc :)

Comment: Do you want to zoom with a square effect (like actually zooming a low-res image) or a 'perfect' zoom (that takes advantage of the new pixels) ??